# Shortcut to fetch all formula field which have hyperlink in full ORG

Tags: apex, formula-field, metadata

Is there any way like script or soql to fetch to all formula field to fetch hyperlink in org. As salesforce is looking for java script disable in hyper link, we are looking for fetching all formula fields with hyper link. I found something like for all account object in org:

```
List<String> lstFields = new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectField fld: Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
    if(fld.getDescribe().getCalculatedFormula() 
!=null && fld.getDescribe().isCalculated())
    {
       system.debug('----field--'+fld.getDescribe().getName());
       lstFields.add(fld.getDescribe().getName()); 
    } 
}
Database.query('SELECT '+String.join(lstFields, ', ')+ ' FROM Account' );
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks Adrian, is there any way to fetch all in script without fetching metadata in eclipse .I heard people are doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this code then variable x will contain all formula fields which contain ***HYPERLINK*** text.

```
String s = '';
String x = '';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for ( String key: globalMap.keySet() ) {
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = globalMap.get( key ).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for ( String fieldKey: fieldsMap.keySet() ) {
        DescribeFieldResult dfr = fieldsMap.get( fieldKey ).getDescribe();
        if ( ! dfr.isCalculated() ) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ Field : ' + key + '.' +fieldKey + ' not a formula' );
        } else {
            String f = dfr.getCalculatedFormula();
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ Field : ' + key + '.' +fieldKey + '?:' + dfr.getCalculatedFormula() );
            s += '(' + key + '.' +fieldKey + ':' + dfr.getCalculatedFormula() + ')'+'\r\n';
            if ( !String.isBlank( f ) && f.contains('HYPERLINK') ) {
                x += '(' + key + '.' +fieldKey + ':' + f + ')'+'\r\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ s: ' + s );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ x: ' + x );
```

Comment: Can we do something so that it will write create csv file and email the fields which have hyperlinks

Comment: yes, I have done something like that in the past

Answer (score 0):

There is one tool where you can do that and have it in Excel. You will even have the formula definition itself.

Using [SpringTool](https://springfive.com/springtool-offer/), you can generate a configuration Workbook for all the objects you want (even with the free version). This workbook will contain all the fields and for the formula fields it will contain the formula itself. It is in Excel format so you can then use Excel search functionality for any keyword you want (in your case, you will want to search for "HYPERLINK(" in all sheets. This will give you all the list of fields that are formula fields containing hyperlinks.